# Background color not working for div containing floating elements

Tags: html, css

If you can see over here http://jsfiddle.net/NE3rZ/3/

I have set the background color to red for my container, but its not showing.

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
}
```

Please help. I need to show the background color if container contains 2 rows and the second row is not fully covered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `overflow: auto` to you container style

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NE3rZ/5/)

Check the same over here [How to make a div grow in height while having floats inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604005/how-to-make-a-div-grow-in-height-while-having-floats-inside)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a clear after the floated elements. I'd suggest using `overflow: hidden` in this case:

http://jsfiddle.net/NE3rZ/4/

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when you don't define a definite(I mean not percentage) WIDTH AND HEIGHT for the parent `div`.
You can either set a `height` property for your parent `div` or use `overflow:auto` property for your parent `div` and the parent will fit its own height automatically based on what's in it!!(it is the best solution for floating child `div`s)